# Device descriptor request failed

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

I tried working with my RPi Pico today and my computer doesn't recognize the usb I triple checked the cable is power and data. And yes I'm holding the button

Answer (score 2):

I've also had this annoying issue. Seems to happen even more often on the Pi Pico W.

Use my laptop USB-C port to connect via a USB-C to USB 3.0 hub and this happens every so often.

Bought a **powered** hub from Amazon: "UGREEN USB C Hub 4 Ports, USB C to USB Hub 3.0". It has a separate USB-C power input in addition to the laptop USB-C connection and it works fine when no other USB devices are connected to the hub. Seems to be an issue similar to what Foibled2 mentioned where the underlying issue may be power related.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue where I could open the boot mode of the pico and upload firmware but I couldn't access the pico outside of boot mode with Thonny. [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AT_4p6Aecow) solved the problem he uploaded a file called [nuke_flash.uf2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aPxh6wQMQ8DqqGY1vgz7uWMim40DIhRa/view) (google drive) which seems to have cleared any possible corrupt files. And then he uploaded micropython firmware ([here](https://micropython.org/download/RPI_PICO/) (for pico only)). **Warning:**
nuke_flash.uf2 will also delete the main.py

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with the same thing.  Other than uninstalling in Device Manager and rebooting (sometimes several times) I can get it to recover.

There must be a better way.

I've seen references to Zadig, etc.  But finally figured out the issue in my circumstance.

I disabled all of my other USB serial devices (Prolific USB for GPS tracker; and CH340 USB for Android Nano).

After that, I could plug / unplug my R Pi Pico between application and USB drive mode without rebooting.

Works now as advertised.